# Saving Word document in code-behind changes style names by language in Word 2013 Add in project

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-2013, word-addins

I have a problem with saving Active Document in Word 2013 that it changes style names after calling Save() Method.

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Save();
```

After I extract that .docx file, I see in styles.xml file that my style names has changed words by language. For example, I have a style name "heading 1", it changes it after save to "Otsikko11". Word "Otsikko" is finnish meaning heading.
How I can prevent this from happening?
My project is Word 2013 Add in

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer how to prevent this from happening. When you create a new style with open xml sdk 2.5:

```
Style style = new Style()
        {
            Type = StyleValues.Paragraph,
            StyleId = styleid,
            CustomStyle = true // LEAVE THIS ONE OUT
        };
```

You have to leave CustomStyle out. Then after saving word document it won't change style names anymore. I accidentally leaved this one out and things started to work out.